# JavaFX, How can I clone a Polygon object

Tags: javafx

I want to ask How can I clone a existed Polygon object?

like this:
    Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p2 = p1.clone();

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Polygon p2 = new Polygon();
p2.getPoints.addAll(p1.getPoints());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But actually, there are other settings for eg. p2 here, so must I  repeat all the same setting again? And it's dynamic, so even sometimes I don't know exactly all the settings.

Comment: Yep, that's horrible. Oracle was too lazy to implement a proper public clone() method I guess.

Comment: Although I suppose since it's a VIEW component, you should have some method of instantiating these view objects from some "model" data source anyway.

Comment: @Manius If you're referring to `clone()`in the `Cloneable` interface, it has many problems, and generally code should not implement it. See the Joshua Bloch book, for example. As you say, it's a UI component, so should be constructed from data in a model. Creational design patterns can also be useful here, depending on context.

Comment: Right, I wasn't thinking of implementing Cloneable, actually I forgot about that mess. Regrettable that made using the word "clone" for anything confusing.